# Showing a tick icon based on enum value in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to make logic to show a tick icon if based on enum value with if value is pending and true
show a tick, if confirmed and true show icon two times and so on. Please help.

```
   enum Status { Pending, Confirmed, Shipped, Received }






Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
     
      child: Row(
        children: [
          widget.title == 'Shipped'
   ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track the selected value index, and render that much widget.

```dart
class CheckStatus extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckStatus({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckStatus> createState() => _CheckStatusState();
}

enum Status { Pending, Confirmed, Shipped, Received }

class _CheckStatusState extends State<CheckStatus> {
  int selectedItemIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < Status.values.length; i++)
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                selectedItemIndex = i;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("btn ${Status.values[i]}"),
            ),
          Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i <= selectedItemIndex; i++) Icon(Icons.check)
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that be creating an extension on your enum
note that to use `describeEnum` you have to add this import to your dart file
`import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';`

```
extension on Status {
    String get value => describeEnum(this);
}
```

and based on it, you can show an icon or a badge

```
 Row(
    children: [
        if(widget.title.value == 'Shipped')
          Icon(Icons.done)
    ]
 ),
```

note that I assumed that the sent title is an enum value